# C# library that validates XML with Schema 1.1?

Tags: library, c#, .net, xml

Is there any C# library that validates an XML document with [XML Schema 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/)? To be specific, I would like to write a schema that accepts [`<any>` in `<all>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22477106/xsany-in-xsall-tag-for-xsd).

Google gives me [RaptorXML](https://www.altova.com/raptorxml), but it seems to provide only an HTTP API, limiting the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saxon-EE for .NET will do the job.

www.saxonica.com

Comment: Thank you. It [explicitly support](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!schema-processing/schema11/allgroups) `<any>` in `<all>`. I will mark this as the answer unless someone come up with a free alternative.